# How can I wire a relay or contactor to an elapsed time meter?

Tags: relay, contactor

For a DIY project, I want to run the tools in my workshop through a special receptacle in which I have connected an elapsed time meter to be triggered when the tool (e.g. drill, saw, etc.) runs.  To test out the concept, I connected the hot wire from my power source to the relay coil (coil rated 120V) then from the other side of the coil to a drill. The neutral wire goes right from the power source to the drill. A hot wire from the power source also goes through the NO relay switch to the elapsed time meter, then from the meter it connects to neutral. When I pull the trigger on the drill, the relay clicks turning on the elapsed time meter as desired, but the drill does not run. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do for the drill to run as well.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you need a current-sensing relay, which are less common than standard relays but I'm pretty sure they do exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to measure the voltage across the relay coil and then across the drill terminals you would find that most - possibly > 95% - is dropped across the relay and there are only a few volts left for the drill motor. The reason is that the relay coil resistance is so much higher than that of the motor. (The reason for that is that the relay requires a lot less current than the drill.)

As @Hearth as suggested you need to give the drill full supply voltage and monitor the **current**.

I would recommend that you have a look at some of the woodwork forums where a similar setup is required to turn on the central vacuum system when one of the dust creating tools is switched on. You should be able to find something like a socket strip which will accept multiple tools and one switched outlet for the vacuum system. You would connect your elapsed hour meter to that socket.

Just check the sensitivity of the device to make sure it can detect your lightest load.

Comment: These socket strips are can be had from office supplies places for controlling power to computer accessories.  sensitivity is about 10 watts.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні, yes, but I think there would be one socket to detect that, say, the TV was drawing power or in standby and all the other sockets would be used for switching the audio, video, etc. It might do the job and be easier to find.